# Oval p-clamps for front rack mounting in fork

Tags: rack

I would love to find some oval p-clips to mount a small front rack on a bicycle without any eyletes. Are there any available? Or any other solution?

Comment: Amazon, eBay, local hardware store, local bike shop...they are readily available and a good solution.

Comment: Do you have any name for them? I can only find the standard p-clamps / p-clips. No oval or even better aero shaped.

Answer (score 4):

P-clips are designed to bend into shape, whether made of steel or plastic.  The steel kind are really quite flexible and will pull into th right shape as you tighten them.  However I suggest using a (fairly large) washer under your fastener (a square washer would be even better) to make sure that the sharpest bend is away from the fastener and supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an online source of p-clamps, maybe you can find something suitable from them:

https://www.mcmaster.com/#p-clamps/=17dx4i8

I haven't bought yet but I saved that link for when I get racks for my MTB-turned-hybrid.